# How to fix multiplying Snipcart custom html in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, snipcart

I recently migrated a site to Gatsby[v2] and found that the custom html for Snipcart multiplies after an event happens.How would I prevent the Snipcart custom HTML from multiplying every time a page navigation or when an event occurs? The multiple rendering is visible when I open the modal. I am not sure whether this is a React component lifecycle issue or a Gatsby[v2] Layout component issue.

The CustomSnipcartText component uses the componentDidMount to call the Snipcart api and use those methods to bind the text to the DOM. The CustomSnipcartText component is imported into the Gatsby Layout component. I have tried importing the component into where the modal function is opened with no change in results.

Snipcart custom html component:

```
  // Binds the Snipcart subscription services to the component
  componentDidMount() {
  /* global Snipcart:false */
    Snipcart.execute('bind', 'cart.opened', function() {
      Snipcart.execute('unbind', 'cart.opened')
      /* global $: false */
      let html = $('#cart-content-text').html()
      $(html).insertBefore($('#snipcart-footer'))
    })
  } ....
```

GatsbyJs Layout component:

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <CustomSnipcartText /> ...
```

I expect the CustomSnipcartComponent should not multiply after any event happening.

Comment: `$(html).insertBefore($('#snipcart-footer'))`. Why?

Comment: I was following Snipcart's instructions on how to add custom html https://snipcart.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-html-to-snipcart.

Answer (score 1):

When your code is run, it appends a new fragment of `#cart-content-text` but if it's not the first time it runs, it will continue to append more.

The Snipcart code isn't aware of the HTML you inject, so you're responsible to remove it OR to update its content.

You'll have to add some logic to check if your custom HTML is already there.

---

Also, [`Snipcart.subscribe`](https://docs.snipcart.com/javascript-api-reference/events#basics) can be used instead of `Snipcart.execute` :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jean-Sébastien-Tremblay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5818389/jean-s%C3%A9bastien-tremblay)'s post I realised the issue was in the Gatsby Layout component.

In version 1 the layout component was a special component that acted as a wrapper outside of the page component. 
In version 2, the [layout](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-layout/#how-layouts-worked-in-version-1) component a regular component where you wrap it on the pages you want to use it. More on the reasoning can be found on the Gatsby [blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-06-08-life-after-layouts/).

All the pages in this project are created dynamically.

I used the `gatsby-plugin-layout` to reimplement the layout from v1. I moved the component outside the components directory back into the layouts directory and changed the file name from `Layout.js` to `index.js`.